# C++ & Xcode - Statically link libraries

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, static-libraries, otool

I have a C++ project and I use Xcode 9.2 and gcc to compile it. I have a list of static libraries linked and you can see some of them in the following picture:

[image: Link Binary With Libraries section of Xcode]

As you can see they are correctly listed into the 'Link Binary With Libraries' section of the 'Build phases' XCode panel.

Everything works right if I run the executable on the same machine used to generate it.
Issues starts when I try to run the binary on another Mac. The program doesn't start and the following message is returned:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Desktop/Joyce
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Running **otool -L** on the executable this is the result:

```
/usr/local/opt/fontconfig/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.1.0)
/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 23.0.0, current version 23.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/cairo/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.2.dylib (compatibility version 11403.0.0, current version 11403.12.0)
/usr/local/opt/cairo/lib/libcairo.2.dylib (compatibility version 11403.0.0, current version 11403.12.0)
/usr/local/opt/cairo/lib/libcairo-gobject.2.dylib (compatibility version 11403.0.0, current version 11403.12.0)
```

So I'm a bit confused about static linking with Xcode, because I'm expecting these library should be statically linked with the executable, but based on the above results they seems dynamically linked instead.

My purpose is to run the executable on others machine without installing further components.

Comment: Does this help? https://jnjosh.com/posts/static-linking-with-c-plus-plus-project-in-xcode/

Comment: It works! In such way I had to manually add some further static library (dependences of my directly imported libs) but I got what I wanted. You should describe the procedure as response. Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore it would be useful to know the reasons behind this curious behavior of Xcode..